# Homotopy between $\mathbb{S}^n$ maps

Tags: algebraic-topology

This question arises from reading Greenberg's book  "Lectures on Algebraic Topology".

Let $f,g \colon \mathbb{S}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{S}^n$ such that $f(x)\neq g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{S}^n$. Then I want to construct a homotopy between $f$ and $A \circ g$ where $A$ is the antipodal map.

This is what I tried so far. I can assume that $g(N)= r\circ f(N)$, where $N$ is the point $(1,0, \dots, 0) \in \mathbb{S}^n$, and $r \in SO(n+1)$. Now I tried to find an homotopy between $r\circ f$ and $A \circ g$, but I wasn't able. If I get the latest I think I would be done, since I know that $r$ is homotopic to the identity map, thus $f$ is homotopic to $A \circ g$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**: Note that $f$ and $A\circ g$ are never antipodal points. So what do you know about $tf(x)+(1-t)(A\circ g)(x)$ for all $x\in S^n$ and $t\in [0,1]$?

Comment: That this is a segment that doesn't cross the origin

Comment: Perfect. So can you use it to get a homotopy $S^n\to S^n$?

Comment: YES.

I can divide this expression $tf(x)+(1-t)(A\circ g)(x)$ by its norm since it doesn't vanish for any $t$ or $x$, so this is a continous map. It also goes to $\mathbb{S}^n$ since the image has norm 1. And for $t=0$ I have $A\circ g$ and for $t=1$ I have $f$. Am I right?

Comment: Yup. Precisely.